# C#: Filter things like `-beta1` and ` hotfix` from a string version number

Tags: c#, .net, string, version

I'm processing some old version strings which are usually in the form `1.2.3`, but sometimes they have stuff tagged on the end such as `-beta1` or `hotfix` (space at start of that).

I want to filter to just the version number, eg. `1.2.3`, with only digits (`0-9`) and periods (`.`) remaining, so that I can pass it to `Version.TryParse()` with a high chance that it will parse.

I've looked at several examples online, but they all seem to focus on numbers like `12.34` and don't work when there are additional period-number parts like `12.34.56`.

Performance is not critical, maintainability is. Which would be the most appropriate approach?

Comment: `string version = Regex.Match(yourString, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+").Value;`

Comment: Have a look at [semver recommended regex](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string) and this online [test](https://regex101.com/r/Ly7O1x/3/) You question is closely related to semantic versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *matching* with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

... 

string source = "some text with 1.2.34.4893-beta1 version" ;

if (Version.TryParse(Regex.Match(source, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+").Value, out var version)) {
  // version  extracted
}
else {
  // source doesn't have a match
}
```